# how to check enterprise github api permissions

Tags: github, github-api, enterprise

I am new to enterprise github. I have just received access to one of the repo belongs to my project. I would like to check whether I have access to APIs. I tried accessing

> http://repo-url/api/v3

but didn't succeed. I am not sure whether I have access to APIs or not. May I know, how to check that?? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone has access to the API. For example, you should be able to run this on your command line:

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/rate_limit
```

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Server: GitHub.com
>
> Date: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 21:13:35 GMT
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> ...
> ```

This proves you have access to the API. But, you can only interact with a repository using the API if your account has the proper permissions to that repository. Run this command

```
curl -u [username] https://api.github.com/repos/[organization]/[repo]/collaborators/[username]/permission
```

Just replace everything in square brackets with the relevant info. Enter a personal access token when prompted for a password (you can [provision a personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) to authenticate in this way). You will then receive a response with your permission level:

> ```
> Status: 200 OK
>
> {
>       "permission": "admin"/"write"/"read"/"none",
>       "user": {
>           ...
> ```

([Source](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#review-a-users-permission-level))

Comment: you are right..but what I am expecting is related to enterprise github

Comment: @YogeshJilhawar I'm pretty sure this will work for github enterprise, just replace the organization with your enterprise name. You may also need to specify hostname as shown [here](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.13/v3/)